# not executing registerstartupscript's javascript after postback

Tags: asp.net, postback

I have such a problem: my page got a custom user control. Custom user contol has onLoad method that contains a line that makes page call a Javascript onLoad.

```
 Page.RegisterStartupScript("recallmenu", "<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>  initAuthGroupList();</script>");
```

While this certainly called during postback too, I receive execution of Javascript in question only on page initial load, but not on post back.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Is this control placed in an UpdatePanel?

Comment: Yes, it is. How I can make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing away update panel made it work.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript` method instead: [ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.registerstartupscript.aspx)